# WinSplit Revolution for openbox?

Tags: windows, window-manager, openbox

When on Windows I commonly use [WinSplit Revolution](http://www.winsplit-revolution.com/) to arrange my windows.

I found a plug-in for compiz fusion that does a similar task, but I am using openbox. Are there any programs that can do the same thing (press hotkeys -> move + resize window) for Openbox?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've cloned WinSplit Revolution with a lightweight C++ program whose only dependency is libx.  It should work under any window manager that is NetWM compliant, which OpenBox claims to be.  It is quite easy to build and install.

http://code.google.com/p/snappy-util/

Answer (score 2):

With Unity is easier:

active <kbd>Block Num</kbd> in your keyboard, choose the window and you have different sizes and positions with this combination:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>8</kbd>
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>7</kbd>
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>9</kbd>
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>4</kbd>
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>5</kbd>
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>6</kbd>
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd>
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>2</kbd>
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>3</kbd>
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>0</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Here's an interesting recent thread from crunchbanglinux :
[My Attempt to Bring Winsplit Revolution to Linux](http://crunchbanglinux.org/forums/topic/11360/my-attempt-to-bring-winsplit-revolution-to-linux/)

There, the user **pico** writes that he is working on a program he calls azelejo .

Pico's brief introduction for the project is here:
[Introducing Azulejo](http://lamehacks.net/blog/introducing-azulejo-user-friendly-window-tilling/)

He has working code on bitbucket that you can try to make sure it works with openbox. (However, openbox is the default windowmanager for crunchbang, so my assumption is that it should.)

Two other possibilities are 
[xmonad](http://xmonad.org/) and [PyTyle](http://pytyle.com/wiki/Main_Page) .

Answer (score 0):

development in azulejo is going slow but steady. I fixed a few bugs and built a deb package so anyone can try it with minimal effort.

http://lamehacks.net/blog/tag/azulejo/

The default keymap looks like this:

```
Super+2     Place two windows side by side
Super+3     Place a window on the left half of the screen and two on the right half
Super+4     Arrange four windows two by two
Super+R     Rotate windows' positions i.e. cycle windows
Super+H     Resize and move current window to the left
Super+K     Resize and move current window to the right
Super+Y     Resize and move current window to left upper corner
Super+U     Resize and move current window to right upper corner
Super+B     Resize and move current window to left lower corner
Super+N     Resize and move current window to right lower corner
```

I tried to make it as customizable as possible. You can redefine everything from keyboard shortcuts to window geometries.
As it is, it fulfills my needs, I'm using it everyday on openbox and sometimes on gnome. I wouldn't mind (it's fun) polishing it a bit more and add a couple of features if it gets a bit of a userbase.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a Python script named [QuickTile](http://ssokolow.com/quicktile/) for this sort of thing and I run Lubuntu, so it's developed and tested primarily under a dual-monitor Openbox setup.

Features:

- Aims to replicate WinSplit Revolution's keybindings (It's actually one of the earlier projects to do this given that it was already usable in 2009 when my git history begins)
- Can also be used to perform other window-manipulation actions such as workspace switching (See `--show-actions`)
- Can be controlled via global hotkeys, command-line arguments, or D-Bus calls
- Trivial to install on Debian-family distros like Ubuntu and Mint. (Click the button on the website to install the dependencies via apt, then unzip and run `quicktile.py`)
- Uses libwnck for window manipulation, so it should work on any X11 desktop
- Written in easily-extended Python (2.x at the moment)